# Nested Square Roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, nested-radicals

Question:

Solve for $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}}$

I know this may be a duplicate but I have not found one yet.

Additionally I understand the logic for base 8 but why would the answer be

$x^\frac 78$

Instead of

$x^\frac 18$

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}}$ is not the same thing as $\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{x}}}$.

Comment: Rewrite $\sqrt{x\sqrt{x\sqrt{x}}}$ as $(x(x(x)^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}})^{\frac{1}{2}}$

Comment: Rather than exponents and multiplication, relate your problem if it were multiplication and addition respectively... that is, compare to the question of if this were $\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{1}{2}(x+\frac{1}{2}(x)))$.  You should be able to tell why this would be $\frac{7}{8}x$ rather than $\frac{1}{8}x$ here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you, that cleared it up for me. I thought it may have been an alternative way of representing √√√x

Comment: What power does the first $x$ get raised to ultimately? What about the second and third $x$s?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Use the following two facts:

1. $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$
2. $\sqrt{\sqrt{a}} = \sqrt{a^\frac12} = \left(a^\frac12\right)^\frac12 = a^{\frac12\cdot\frac12} = a^\frac14$

Comment: I am aware of that but do not see where 7/8 comes from

Comment: @PleaseSirMayIHaveSomeMore Well, what did you try so far? For example, did you try to apply the first equality ($\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt a\sqrt b$) to your expression? If yes, then what did you get? If no, then... why not?